# User based authorization opensource chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo, knife

Is user based authorization possible in opensource chef?

I created two users using knife user create command.One as admin and other as normal user.

Admin user has all the priveleges as it has to be.But normal user can only create cookbook and list few things.

Can we place restrictions such thats particular user can only edit cookbooks and upload them that has been created by him?

Answer (score 1):

open source chef don't have that functionality.Only admin and non admin users.Enterprise chef has role based access control, not sure about its support to your requirement.